# Transcribing non-native speakers of English who are presenters at an international conference?

Tags: conference, international

An international conference on sericulture will be held in Japan soon, and I need to create a transcription of the oral presentations. There will be 10 to 20 presentations, and almost all speakers will likely be non-native speakers of English.

I have little experience listening to non-native speakers. Also, I’ve only transcribed interviews so far. Do you think I can transcribe the presentations myself, or would it be a huge hassle?  Should I use a transcription service? I want to save money if I can. Transcribing half of it myself and hiring a transcription service for the other half might be the way.

I record the presentations then transcribe at home. The language of the conference is English.

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Why do you need to create transcripts?

Comment: The transcripts are needed so that writers can summarize each presentation. There will be one article per presentation, and the articles will make up the international conference final report.

Comment: So you work for the conference? Have they given you a budget? It seems so, since you want to save money. This seems like a question you should ask your supervisor.

Comment: You might find this [ResearchGate thread](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_software_for_transcription_of_interviews2) on transcription software and services useful.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. You record the presentations then transcribe at home. It's just matter of time you have and you need to spend. If a presenter has thick accent, you just need to spend more time to listen to the recording. That's all. What's the problem? If you have time limit, then yes, you might need to hire people to do it as fast they can It's a business decision, balance between money and time. Vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @Azor Ahai Thanks, I've spoken to people.

Comment: @Anyon Thanks also, I'll read through the thread. I've been looking at Temi, a transcription service.

Comment: @scaaahu I only have so much time to transcribe them. I mean no disrespect. I happened to discover some things and I just became worried. It's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean that the language of the conference is English and that people will be trying to do their best to speak English.

I think that, while it might be possible that you do it yourself, you are trading time for money. It probably can't be done quickly by a single person, no matter the skills, so a service might be much quicker. I assume that transcribing the talks into "better - more standard" English will require some consultation with each speaker on various subtleties. So, yes, a huge hassle, though do-able if you have the time.

I think it would be even harder unless you are familiar with the native language of each speaker.

I think you will also want to get each speaker to sign off on your transcription, however it is done. Some may have questions or even corrections.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I too suspect that it might be too much work. I'll start looking for a transcription service that I can afford.

Comment: @Buffy I'll remember to do that. Thank you.

Comment: @Buffy gets me as well :)